# Pl/SQL multiple sql statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

If i want to put multiple SQL statements in the PL/SQL block below, how do i do that

SQL statements:

```
select * from XXFMSLS.XXFM_FAH_EVNT_STGG_ARCH  where
bch_id in ('SM_1');

select * from XXFMSLS.XXFM_FAH_EVNT_TXNS_HDR where
bch_id in ('SM_1');



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LAITEST
IS            
l_owner varchar2(30) := 'XXFMSLS';
l_batch varchar2(300) := 'PL_XFER_4';
l_sql varchar2(32000);
begin
l_sql := 'select * from XXFM_FAH_EVNT_CTRL where owner = ''' || l_owner || ''' and bch_id= ''' ||
l_batch || '''';
dbms_output.put_line( l_sql);
end
```

Comment: I am not sure, what you want to do.
What do you want to do, with the SQL-statements? Just output them ? Than why are you not doing it after each other?

Comment: I want to generate multiple SQL statements with same batch I'd for certain tables

Comment: So, why are you not putting multiple dbms_output.put_line after each other?

Comment: That works but is there better way without putting multiple dams output ?

Comment: Not sure if I got that ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LAITEST

IS            

l_owner varchar2(30) := 'XXFMSLS';

l_batch varchar2(300) := 'PL_XFER_4';

l_sql varchar2(32000);

begin

l_sql := 'select * from XXFM_FAH_EVNT_CTRL where owner = ''' || l_owner || ''' and bch_id= ''' ||

l_batch || '''
select * from XXFMSLS.XXFM_FAH_EVNT_STGG_ARCH  where owner = ''' || l_owner || ''' and bch_id= ''' ||

l_batch || '''';

dbms_output.put_line( l_sql);

end;
```

Comment: It gives error : error line 47 col 3 ending-line 47 ending_col 3 expecting : identifier string or ;

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have oracle installed on this PC, so I have to guess: there was a ; missend at the last line

Comment: Sql with subquery not printed begin   l_sql := 'select * from XXFM_FAH_EVNT_CTRL where owner = ''' || l_owner || ''' and bch_id= ''' ||   l_batch || ''' select * from XXFM_FAH_EVNT_STGG_ARCH  where owner = ''' || l_owner || ''' and bch_id= ''' ||   l_batch || ''' select * from XXFM_FAH_EVNT_TXNS_HDR  where owner = ''' || l_owner || ''' and bch_id= ''' ||   l_batch || '''   select * from XXFM_FAH_EVNT_TXNS_LINE  where owner = ''' || l_owner || ''' and  sls_evnt_id in (select sls_evnt_id from XXFM_FAH_EVNT_TXNS_HDR where bch_id in ('') )' ||   l_batch || '''' ;   dbms_output.put_line( );

Comment: Is it possible to parametrized values that hard coded?

Comment: I was able to parametrized the values

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LAITEST (bch_id  in varchar2)
IS            
   pattern varchar2(50) := 'XXFM_FAH_EVNT';
   onwer varchar2(50) := 'XXFMSLS';

begin
      for t_name  in (select u_t.TABLE_NAME from all_tables u_t where u_t.OWNER = onwer and u_t.TABLE_NAME like '%'||pattern||'%')
      loop
          l_sql := 'select * from '|| t_name || ' where bch_id = ' || bch_id;
          dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
      end loop;
end;
```

You could also use user_tables instead if you are the owner of the tables and/or cannot access all_tables for any reason.